# Is it possible to change size of DropdownMenuItem in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a DropdownButton that when it's open looks like this.

[image]

Is it possible to make it narrower to adjust to the text?

This is my DropdownButton:

```
      DropdownButton<dynamic>(
        value: state.locale.languageCode,
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: 'EN',
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Text(
                'EN',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: 'DE',
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Text(
                'DE',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          dropdownCallback(newValue, state);
        },
        underline: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(child: Container()),
      ),
```

I have tried to wrap it in sized boxes, both the Button and Menu items, and it doesn't work. I can't find any parameters in the documentation to help me with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your Dropdown with Container and Set width it hope its help to you

```
Container(
      width: 25,
      child: DropdownButton<dynamic>(
        isExpanded: true,
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: 'EN',
            child: Text(
              'EN',
            ),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: 'DE',
            child: Text(
              'DE',
            ),
          ),
        ],
        onChanged: (newValue) {},
        underline: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(child: Container()),
      ),
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: I tried this already, but I need to change only the width of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like below.

```
 Container(
            width: 45,
            child:   DropdownButton<dynamic>(
              value: "EN",
              itemHeight: 50.0,
              isExpanded: true,
              items: [
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 'EN',
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      'EN',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: 'DE',
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      'DE',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                // dropdownCallback(newValue, state);
              },
              underline: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(child: Container()),
              // },
            ) ,
          )
```

Comment: That would work for height but I need to change the width

Comment: yes it will also change width. just give width to container and make          
 isExpanded: true, thats it.

Comment: No but the probelm is that I need to change the width of the items not the button, so the items need to be smaller than the button